I want to change the tint of my panoramic skybox for daylight cycle
So i am trying to create a daylight cycle, where it switches between two panoramic images. The change happens slowly one over 2 minutes and the other over 3. During this the fog and light changes color but the image of the sky just slowly fades from one image to another. I would like for the skybox color to change too using the tint option. But how do i do this in my code so that the tint of the sky will match the color of the light and fog? This is in unity 3d btw using C# if that wasn't already obvious.
The code:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TimeManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Texture2D skyboxNight;
    [SerializeField] private Texture2D skyboxDay;

    [SerializeField] private Gradient graddientNightToDay;
    [SerializeField] private Gradient graddientDayToNight;

    [SerializeField] private Light globalLight;

    public int minutes;

    public int Minutes
    { get { return minutes; } set { minutes = value; OnMinutesChange(value); } }

    public int hours = 5;

    public int Hours
    { get { return hours; } set { hours = value; OnHoursChange(value); } }

    private int days;

    public int Days
    { get { return days; } set { days = value; } }

    private float tempSecond;

    public void Update()
    {
        tempSecond += Time.deltaTime;

        if (tempSecond >= 1)
        {
            Minutes += 1;
            tempSecond = 0;
        }
    }

    private void OnMinutesChange(int value)
    {
        globalLight.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, (1f / (1440f / 4f)) * 360f, Space.World);
        if (value >= 60)
        {
            Hours++;
            minutes = 0;
        }
        if (Hours >= 24)
        {
            Hours = 0;
            Days++;
        }
    }

    private void OnHoursChange(int value)
    {
        if (Hours >= 24)
        {
            Hours = 0;
            Days++;
        }
        if (value == 6)
        {
            StartCoroutine(LerpSkybox(skyboxNight, skyboxDay, 120f));
            StartCoroutine(LerpLight(graddientNightToDay, 120f));
        }
        else if (value == 18)
        {
            StartCoroutine(LerpSkybox(skyboxDay, skyboxNight, 240f));
            StartCoroutine(LerpLight(graddientDayToNight, 240f));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator LerpSkybox(Texture2D a, Texture2D b, float time)
    {
        RenderSettings.skybox.SetTexture("_Texture1", a);
        RenderSettings.skybox.SetTexture("_Texture2", b);
        RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Blend", 0);
        for (float i = 0; i < time; i += Time.deltaTime)
        {
            RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Blend", i / time);
            yield return null;
        }
        RenderSettings.skybox.SetTexture("_Texture1", b);
    }

    private IEnumerator LerpLight(Gradient lightGradient, float time)
    {
        for (float i = 0; i < time; i += Time.deltaTime)
        {
            globalLight.color = lightGradient.Evaluate(i / time);
            RenderSettings.fogColor = globalLight.color;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}  ```



Have you tried setting RenderSettings.skybox.color?

@Kevin pretty sure that only works for a procedural skybox, but if that did work, how would i even implement it to work as a gradient? pretty new to coding and stuff
